# How can I correctly include a (non-fragment) # in a URL?

Tags: 8, uri

I need to build an external URL that looks like this:

```
https://searchapp.foo.gov/search-org/#/collection-name?q=search%20terms%20here
```

First thought is that /#/ is entirely invalid according to RFC 3986, unless I'm reading it incorrectly, but that's what I've been given. So I'm building it like so:

```
$base_url = 'https://searchapp.foo.gov/search-org/#/collection-name';
$options = [
  'absolute' => TRUE,
  'https' => TRUE,
  'query' => [
    'q' => $form_state->getValue('search'),
  ],
];
$url = Url::fromUri($base_url, $options)->toString();
```

Instead of the expected output, I find that my querystring is appearing before the #:

```
https://searchapp.foo.gov/search-org/?q=search%20terms%20here#/collection-name
```

I've tried using /%23/ instead of /#/, and that fixes the problem with the querystring being out of place, but creates a new problem by url encoding the %, so that I wind up with /%2523/.

I'm guessing this is a problem with hash segment handling. Is there a right way to handle a URL like this?

Comment: Everything after the # is the fragment that means you have to build that together yourself and provide id as the 'fragment' argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct ... it is invalid to use the "#" for anything other than a fragment. That does not mean that someone doesn't have their web servers setup in such a way that "#" can be used in the URL itself.

> I'm guessing this is a problem with hash segment handling. Is there a right way to handle a URL like this?

To be clear, there is no problem with how Drupal is handling URLs ... Drupal is following the spec. I think your best bet in this case (short of yelling at whoever is giving you this URL for doing so) is to extend the [Url class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/8.4.x) and replace the formUri method to handle your weird case.

Your other option is to do something really hacky like putting an easily replaced string in the URL and then doing a string replace at the last minute before displaying it.

Comment: Just wanted to note that some older apps that make use of Angular will run into this problem.

Comment: Thank you. As it happens, I had the opportunity to yell at people about the URL, and the problem is going to be fixed at the source.